# Create GCE instance using Python API

Tags: python, image, ubuntu, google-compute-engine

I want to create a Google Compute Engine instance using the Python api. In particular, I want the source image to be Ubuntu 14.04.

In the doc, it is written to specify the json body of the request as follows:

```
{
  "name": "example-instance",
  "machineType": "zones/us-central1-f/machineTypes/f1-micro"
  "networkInterfaces": [{
    "accessConfigs": [{
      "type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT",
      "name": "External NAT"
     }],
    "network": "global/networks/default"
  }],
  "disks": [{
     "autoDelete": "true",
     "boot": "true",
     "type": "PERSISTENT",
     "initializeParams": {
        "sourceImage": "projects/debian-cloud/global/images/v20150818"
     }
   }]
}
```

How can I modify the `sourceImage` parameter value so that it points to the ubuntu 14.04 image? Indeed, the syntax "projects/debian-cloud/global/images/v20150818" is too specific to understand how to use it for other public images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you're referring to [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide#addinganinstance) ([source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/compute/api/create_instance.py)) which use the following URL format:

```
"projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-7-wheezy-v20150320"
```

The pattern here is:

```
"projects/${PROJECT}/global/images/${IMAGE}"
```

You can find the available images via:

```
$ gcloud compute images list
```

which will show you output similar to the following:

```
NAME                                PROJECT            ALIAS              DEPRECATED STATUS
centos-6-v20151104                  centos-cloud       centos-6                      READY
centos-7-v20151104                  centos-cloud       centos-7                      READY
coreos-alpha-891-0-0-v20151211      coreos-cloud                                     READY
coreos-beta-877-1-0-v20151202       coreos-cloud                                     READY
coreos-stable-835-9-0-v20151208     coreos-cloud       coreos                        READY
backports-debian-7-wheezy-v20151104 debian-cloud       debian-7-backports            READY
debian-7-wheezy-v20151104           debian-cloud       debian-7                      READY
debian-8-jessie-v20151104           debian-cloud       debian-8                      READY
container-vm-v20151103              google-containers  container-vm                  READY
opensuse-13-1-v20150822             opensuse-cloud     opensuse-13                   READY
opensuse-13-2-v20150511             opensuse-cloud     opensuse-13                   READY
opensuse-leap-42-1-v20151124        opensuse-cloud                                   READY
rhel-6-v20151104                    rhel-cloud         rhel-6                        READY
rhel-7-v20151104                    rhel-cloud         rhel-7                        READY
sles-11-sp4-v20150714               suse-cloud         sles-11                       READY
sles-12-sp1-v20151215               suse-cloud         sles-12                       READY
ubuntu-1204-precise-v20151119       ubuntu-os-cloud    ubuntu-12-04                  READY
ubuntu-1404-trusty-v20151113        ubuntu-os-cloud    ubuntu-14-04                  READY
ubuntu-1504-vivid-v20151120         ubuntu-os-cloud    ubuntu-15-04                  READY
ubuntu-1510-wily-v20151114          ubuntu-os-cloud                                  READY
windows-server-2008-r2-dc-v20151006 windows-cloud      windows-2008-r2               READY
windows-server-2012-r2-dc-v20151006 windows-cloud      windows-2012-r2               READY
```

So in the case of Ubuntu 14.04, the image path would be:

```
"projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-1404-trusty-v20151113"
```

You can also find out more metadata about an image via:

```
$ gcloud compute images describe --project ubuntu-os-cloud ubuntu-1404-trusty-20151113
```

and the `selfLink` attribute in the output will provide a full URL to the image.